# Reload php include on button click

Tags: php

I am a beginner on using php mysql and basically what I am trying to do is in index.php on form submit it inserts the data in mysql and then I query  and store 2-3 column values of same data in another php file lets say data.php. Now I have included data.php in index.php and on every submit want to reload data.php and display latest values from the same in a data table in index.php.

Long story short, reload a include php file containing variables on button click to display latest values everytime after form submit. Below is the code

```
<?php
include("data.php");
?>
<html>
<form id="signupform"></form>
<button onclick="postdata()"></button>

<table>
<tr>
<td>var1 in data.php:</td> <td>value of var1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>var2 in data.php:</td> <td>value of var2</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>  
function postdata() {

            var data = $("#signupform").serialize();
    $.post('submit.php', data, function(data,status){
      console.log("");
    });

document.getElementById("var1").innerHTML = '<?php echo $var1; ?>' ;
document.getElementById("var2").innerHTML = '<?php echo $var2; ?>' ;

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code? (Just edit the question)

Comment: PHP is loaded once and cannot be re-loaded without re-loading the current page without JQuery AJAX methods

Comment: Did you close off the php tag here?  `<?php
include("data.php");
<html>` should throw you a parse error by introducing pure HTML. You only closed it at the end which is incorrect.

Comment: Ok, so you're editing "on the fly". That for me makes the question unclear. You have to post the actual code. Otherwise, I can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

If its a form make the action="time.php" and on the time.php page after you insert the data use header("location: index.php");

Comment: Sorry for silly question. Where do i need to add header("location: index.php"); ? in index.php

Comment: You should put it in the time.php or any page where the query occurs. Eg. $insert = mysqli_query($con,"your query"); if($insert){ header("location: index.php");}

Answer (score 0):

PHP code is [server-side code](https://www.codeconquest.com/website/client-side-vs-server-side/) that finishes executing before the page is actually sent to the browser. What this effectively means is that you can't execute php code when the user does something like clicking a button.

There are effectively two solutions for 'reloading' the data from an included php file:

Reload the entire page after you've posted the form data:

```
$.post('submit.php', data, function(data,status){ 
console.log(""); 
window.location.reload();
});
```

Or fetch the output of the other PHP file (assuming data.php) with Jquery after your post to submit.php is done, and then insert the result into the DOM:

```
$.post('submit.php', data, function(data,status){ 
    console.log(""); 
    $.ajax({
      url: "url/to/data.php",
      method: "get",
      success: function(output){
          $("#html-element-id-here").html(output);
      }
    })
});
```